# JavaScript: search for multiple values in a string and return the match

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, search

If I have an array of words and a string. How could i do a simple search for the keywords, and then stop at the first hit, and return which keyword that mathed? It is certainly a simple solution but is a bit stuck on the problem.

Comment: Well, for a start we'd appreciate you sharing the code rather than assumptions; what string do you have? What word(s) are you looking for? How do you want the result returned, what format should it have? When you tried to solve this question for yourself how far did you get, and where did you get stuck? What went wrong, and in what way? Please: take the [tour], read the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidance and then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the first match you can break out
of the loop over the array with `break`:

```
array = ["red", "green", "blue"];
string = "little red riding hood brought green peppers";

found = false; 
for( word of array) {
  if(string.indexOf(word) > -1) {
    found=word; 
    break; 
  } 
}

if(found) {
  console.log("I found the word", found);
} else {
  console.log("non of the words were found);
}
```